# Need the count of the particular <li> tag clicked

Tags: jquery

```
<ul>
    <li><div><a href="#">line a</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#">line b</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#">line c</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#">line d</a></div></li>
    <li><div><a href="#">line e</a></div></li>
</ul>
```

The output that I need is to get the position(count) of the `<li>` tag. I cant use the `index()` for this.
For eg., if I click on "Line a", the output I need to get is "1", for "Line b" I need "2"; and so on.

I cant use the index().

Comment: Why can't you use `index` (on the closest li) ?

Comment: What element are you binding your click event to?

Comment: Why can't you use index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.index()` should work fine if you use it relative to the clicked element: `$('a').index(this)`

Samplecode:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').on('click', function() {
        alert($('a').index(this)+1);

        return false;
    });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vjV7Y/10/

Note: I've added `+1` because `index()` returns `0` for the first element and not `1`.

Answer (score 3):

You *can* use index :

```
$('li a').click(function(){
   console.log('index is ' + ($(this).closest('li').index()+1));
});
```

Comment: What if what he meant was that he himself can't use `.index()`, not that the problem was such that `.index()` can't be used :)

Comment: That's how I understood it. But as I'm still unsure, I asked in comment the reason why he can't use index.

Comment: actually wen i use index() function, i always get the output as "-1"

Comment: @DebjeetDas you probably didn't use `closest` as I propose to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function(){
   var li = $(this).parent().parent(); //current li
   var ul = li.parent().children(); //all ul children li's
   alert('Index: ' + ul.index(li));
});
```